# What was the antagonist trying to accomplish?

Tags: plot-explanation, incredibles-2

*Incredibles 2* starts with all superheroes banned because society has grown tired of cleaning up their messes, and perhaps because people are jealous of their great abilities, as seen at the start of the first *The Incredibles* movie.

The Deavor siblings launch an effort to rehabilitate the reputation of superheroes and legalize their activities. This effort is successful, but the viewer discovers that the bad-guy,

> Evelyn Deavor, actually wants to ban all super-heroes.
>
>
>    Her plan is to help legalize them, and then film them doing something horrible so that they can be banned again.

Why? This seems to be a complex way of doing nothing at all.

Answer (score 11):

The intention is to *permanently* sour the world to super heroes. I'm pretty sure she actually emphasizes the word "permanently" at some point in her explanation to ElastiGirl.

Through the actions of her brother and others who want to allow supers to go back to protecting communities, there is increasing support for legalizing superheroes. By showing that they are actually villains who only want the attention or aren't doing heroic things for selfless reasons, she's further souring the world to them while also counteracting and even possibly discrediting this support. A "win-win" for her - were she successful.